# How to setup a cluster by Kubespray which can preserve source ip from clients?

Tags: kubernetes

I use Kubespray to setup my cluster and run my applications on it. However, my applications need getting client source ip. Therefore, I need set externalTrafficPolicy as Local in svc. But this is not a good solution, especially for building HA applications.

I tried Calico + ebpf, but it doesn't work. (see https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/7252). I aslo tried Cilium and client source ip isn't preserved in this way.

If I want to preserve client source ip, how do I do if using Kubespray?

Comment: To preserve you should implement ingress controllers which will come LB service which can be attached to Load balancer.  Post that enabling proxy protocol, client ip can be preserved.  Following link has different controllers https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/.  depending on your requirement you can choose one.

Comment: What was the issue with Cilium and externalTrafficPolicy?

Comment: Note that, with Cilium, you can also use DSR to preserve the source IP address (and improve performance): https://cilium.io/blog/2020/02/18/cilium-17/#kubeproxy-removal.

Comment: To Nataraj, Ingress controller also is exposed by MetalLB, and it also cannot get client source ip, right? Unless MetalLB SVC for Ingress controll is also added externalTrafficPolicy=Local. So the problem still exists.

Comment: To Pchaigno, Yes, DSR. However, I don't know how to enable DSR in Kubespray. Cannont find any config for that.

Comment: I tried add 'bpf-lb-mode: dsr' in cilium-config, but it doesn't work.